# How to keep same windows separate in Windows 7 desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

This question is about Windows 7 (Win 7) desktop. By default Win 7 keeps all windows of similar type together. But I don't like this setting. I want to keep all windows be of same type or different to be separate. For example if you open three instances of Chrome I want them to be separate so that I could move one window on the taskbar next to some other window and keep the two other in the same place as they are.

One way of doing this is using a third party software like [Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) which I was using. But now it has stopped working and also its download page is not opening. I guess Win 7 has stopped supporting it now or there is some bug in the software. So are there any other apps/software of this kind or may be there is some setting in Win 7 itself to achieve this? Kindly guide me on that.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to remove the section about asking for similar products, those sort of questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Windows natively supports this.

Right-click the taskbar and choose Customize. (alternatively: Control Panel -> Taskbar)

There is a setting: Combine:

Change this to: Never.

If this is not what you're after, software is required, but Software recommendations are off-topic here on SuperUser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what I was looking for. I already have that setting. After uncombining them I want each and every window to be separate and not be grouped in case they are similar.

Comment: “I want each and every window to be separate and not be grouped …”  It seems to me that that’s what this answer does, so I don’t understand your question (and, apparently, neither does LPChip). If you want this thread to be useful to anybody in the future, you should edit your question to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. Actually my antivirus was recognising Taskbar Tweaker as malware and uninstalled it and also not allowing its website to open. After disabling antivirus for a few minutes I installed it again and it works again now.

Comment: Does this not concern you at all? There is a reason your AV software flagged this. I would strongly recommend running malware sweeps.

Comment: @Burgi: No not that concerning. My antivirus shows false negatives sometimes. Other antivirus didn't show it as malware so I guess its safe.